# File handling do not work in codeblocks but fine in turboC++

Tags: c, file, codeblocks

I am trying read file using fscanf in a loop but when i execute it, windows show that file.exe has stopped working. Literally, this program work fine in turboC++(**use clrscr() instead of system("cls")**). I know there is a major difference between these two compilers, i am not able to figure it out. Please help me thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
   FILE *fp;
    char *c;
    system("cls");
   fp = fopen("test.txt", "w+");
   fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf...\n");
   fputs("This is testing for fputs...\n", fp);
   rewind(fp);
   while(!feof(fp)){
        fscanf(fp,"%s",c);
        printf("%s\n",c);
   }
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you even try `tyrboC++`? Give the exact error message.

Comment: It works on my computer, removing `#include <conio.h>` (Debian with gcc 5). Where is the trouble ? Use a debugger.

Comment: there is no buffer allocated to `c`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Oh I did not saw it ^^ Will you write the answer ?

Comment: @Boiethios: Having run the program using a memory checker like Valgrind (http://valgrind.org) you would have seen it.

Comment: @alk Oh, yes, valgrind says `Use of uninitialised value of size 8` I am not (yet) familiar with it, but I see I must do.

Comment: You need to study arrays and pointers, before using arrays and pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't allocated any memory to `c` before calling `fscanf(fp,"%s",c);`.
Thus, `fscanf()` tries to write data to an arbitrary address which invokes Undefined Behaviour. you should either declare `c` as an array

```
char c[SOME_LENGTH+1];
```

or use `malloc()`

```
c = malloc( SOME_LENGTH+1 );
```

Furthermore, as @alk hat mentioned in his comment, it's safer to use maximum length in `scanf()` as well:

```
#define SOME_LENGTH 42
...
fscanf( fp, "%42s", c );
```

You could also use [Stringifcation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) but you will need two levels of macros

```
#define SOME_LENGTH     42
#define STR(L)          #L
#define SCANFFMT(L)     "%" STR(L) "s"
...
fscanf( fp, SCANFFMT(SOME_LENGTH), c );
```

Comment: I might be worth mentioning that the value `#define`d to be `SOME_LENGTH` should go into the format specified by `scanf()` as well. Like `fscanf(fp, "%42s", c);` (assuming `#define SOME_LENGTH 42`)

Comment: Better : `fscanf( fp, "%" #SOME_LENGTH "s", c );`

Comment: @Ingo thanks, it work fine. As a issue i think c[ ] is same as *c. So I didn't try bother over there because i read it in K&R.

Comment: @Boiethos it's a little bit more complicated, look at my last edit